# OpenSSL: BIGNUM's bin2bn doesn't allocate a new BIGNUM when output ptr is null

Tags: c++, c, openssl, cryptography, bignum

According to [OpenSSL 1.1.0's manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_bin2bn.html), it says:

> BN_bin2bn() converts the positive integer in big-endian form of length len at s into a BIGNUM and places it in ret. If ret is NULL, a new BIGNUM is created.

But then in the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "200ec31326d7a933222e3b43a7d6c920a1d2e8a74d1e6f4980ca78b2d9c1aaba6c2ad71f0f1d0cbb40695f27be048982589bccf30066a8735db4a6b0928925077e";
    std::vector<unsigned char> out;
    // convert hex to binary bytes
    boost::algorithm::unhex(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
    BIGNUM *eccsig_r = nullptr;
    // convert bytes to a BIGNUM object
    BN_bin2bn(&out[1],  32, eccsig_r);
    std::cout<<eccsig_r<<std::endl; // prints 0!
    return 0;
}
```

The pointer address of `eccsig_r` remains 0 (or nullptr). If I understand what the manual says, it should be that `eccsig_r` is never `nullptr` again after calling `bin2bn()`.

Why is `eccsig_r` still `nullptr`? I can't understand this. Please advise. I'm on [Debian 9](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl-dev).

PS: For full disclosure, that hex you see up there is a simple ECC signature that I serialized. I don't believe that has any effect on this. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: why did you replace the C tag when this is plainly not C code?

Comment: @WeatherVane Because this problem is not exclusive for C++. OpenSSL is plain C, and people coding in C may still need the same question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think I figured it out. If `ret` is `nullptr`, then the *return value* will create a new BIGNUM in the return of `bin2bn()`. It's a weird way of doing things, in my opinion. I don't understand the purpose, but this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "200ec31326d7a933222e3b43a7d6c920a1d2e8a74d1e6f4980ca78b2d9c1aaba6c2ad71f0f1d0cbb40695f27be048982589bccf30066a8735db4a6b0928925077e";
    std::vector<unsigned char> out;
    // convert hex to binary bytes
    boost::algorithm::unhex(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
    BIGNUM *eccsig_r = nullptr;
    // convert bytes to a BIGNUM object
    eccsig_r = BN_bin2bn(&out[1],  32, nullptr);
    std::cout<<eccsig_r<<std::endl; // doesn't print zero anymore!
    return 0;
}
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The idea is that the function returns the value, so you can directly use it  (e.g. for method chaining or in an expression). The argument is just there for you to save space; you can reuse a buffer. Hope that makes sense to you :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for explaining. I can imagine it's useful in some cases, but still, feels redundant. Thanks for confirming that I got it right. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe it's a bit less useful for C structs compared to Object Oriented languages. You cannot do all that much with the reference other than to assign it, but you could at least perform the declaration and assignment to `eccsig_r` in a single line.